# Why is .htaccess redirecting to `default.asp` and what it is?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is the content of my .htaccess file:

```
Options MultiViews
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.lventas.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://lventas.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://lventas.com/negocio/$1 [L,QSA]

ErrorDocument 404 http://www.lventas.com/404.php
RewriteOptions Inherit
```

It isn't supposed to do nothing when going to the root folder but it's still redirecting to:

```
http://lventas.com/negocio/default.asp
```

What is 'default.asp'?? and why is directing there?

Comment: Is it redirecting to that or is that directory configured to return default.asp as its default document (DirectoryIndex)

Comment: default.asp is a file associated with microsoft active server pages, hence its likely there is some existing configurations interfering. You can paste the output of `apachectl -S` for a list of all the vhosts configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @uSlackr mentioned in the comment, one of the parent configurations likely contains a directive like so;

```
 DirectoryIndex default.asp
```

The `DirectoryIndex` directive provides a default resource for when the client requests a directory i.e. `http://www.lventas.com/` hence the request is mapped to the filesystem relative to the `DocumentRoot` as `REQUEST_FILENAME=/default.asp`

However, as default.asp does not exist as a file, a directory or a link, it then matches your second RewriteRule like so;

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://lventas.com/negocio/$1 [L,QSA]
```

so the final request is `http://lventas.com/negocio/default.asp`

You can usually override this like so;

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

Options MultiViews
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.lventas.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://lventas.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://lventas.com/negocio/$1 [L,QSA]

ErrorDocument 404 http://www.lventas.com/404.php
RewriteOptions Inherit
```

or it seems like it might be possible to just unset the `DirectoryIndex` like so;

```
DirectoryIndex

Options MultiViews
...
```